# Can JavaScript in a Site Access SharePoint Lists?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

If I have a site, completely independent of Microsoft (a Wordpress site), could I access data from lists on a SharePoint site using JS on the external site? For example, I can access lists with the following code in the SharePoint site:

```
function retrieveChemicalsListItems() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/sites/________/');
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ChemicalsTable');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
//<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where> <RowLimit>10</RowLimit>
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onChemicalsQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

}

If I just took this, with the same URL and everything, and put it on any other site, would it work just the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Sharepoint online or on premise? If you use online, go to [link with tutorial for SP Online](http://woodoweb.com/?p=250). But it's not good idea to pass login and password through js code, because everybody will see it. It's a security threat.

Or see this for onprem: [link 1](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/accessing-office-365-sharepoint-sites-using-rest-from-a-local-html-javascript-host/), [link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870858.aspx#BuildMobileAppsInSharePoint2013ForNonWindowsPhone_AuthenticatingNonWindowsAppForSharePoint). Also, using CSOM can help with developing application:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("sp_site_url")) {
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");
    context.Load(list);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    // process list
}
```

Another way is develop your own web service which will have access to Sharepoint site and you will be able to call it with using your custom authentication.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need but the link they provide at the bottom for accessing local data files using Html and Chrome is invalid and I can't find a solution to this error anywhere else.  EDIT: This is in reference to the first link you provided.